# Eclipse - Difference between Build configuration and Run configuration

Tags: c++, eclipse

I recently started to use Eclipse for C++. I'm trying to figure out how "Build configuration" and "Run/Debug configuration" are related. I made a "debug" build config and a "release" build config but no matter which one I set as active the same one is being used for running the program. Now under the "Run" menu there is a Run and a Debug configuration (which bring up the same window) and there I can choose "C/C++ application" and that sets which build will be run. Is this the way I am supposed to choose which build config I want to build/run? I totally don't get how all that works

Comment: When you select the executable to run in the run config, it sticks. I believe you're stuck making two run configurations, one for debug and one for release. I would love for someone to tell me I'm wrong. It would make my life easier.

Comment: @user4581301 I see. Now I created two run configurations. Is there any way to choose between them other than this "Run configuration" window? It seems like simply choosing one config in this window won't remember it, I have to double-click on it to run, and only then it will remember it. Also, it still doesn't seem to change which build-config is being built. Am I supposed to choose the build config and run config separately?

Comment: All of your run configurations should be selectable if you click the down arrowheads to the right of the debug and run buttons. Annoting, but like I said, I'd love to be proven wrong.

Comment: @user4581301 For that I need to make the toolbar visible and I also can't do it with a hotkey.